# spring can not receive csrf token from angular request

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

So I have this problem where I can't get any further. My backend returns a csrf token on every request (httpbasic disabled).
But somehow even though I send it back to spring through angular I get a 403 error...

spring boot config:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        };
    }
```

angular (request):

```
 let _csrf = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("name", "name")
      let post = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/testpost"

      this.http.post(post, formData, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set("_csrf", _csrf)
      })
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
      }
```

an the token gets sent:
[_csrf token sent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeXLr.png)

Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Spring Security by default expects it as a parameter, so sending it is a header won't work without reconfiguring Spring Security.